# Mutliple dynamically sized UILabels are not displayed

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, object

I am trying to add UILabels with variable size.

The labels contain comments from users. I have here tried to implement dynamic sizing of my labels and then I add them to my view (Wich I later add to the main view)

I know that this would make the labels appear **ontop** of eachother, but that is not the problem. The labels are not showing at all.

```
NSMutableDictionary *comments = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[comments setObject:@"xxxxxxxxx" forKey:@"simon"];
[comments setObject:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" forKey:@"pontus"];
[comments setObject:@"xxxxx" forKey:@"sudden"];
[comments setObject:@"xxxx" forKey:@"juan"];
[comments setObject:@"xxxxxxxxxxx" forKey:@"eric"];

DetailedViewController *detailedBurger= [[DetailedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

for(NSString *key in comments){
    UILabel *label =  [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.text = [comments objectForKey:key]; //etc...
    [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"PatuaOne-Regular" size:12.0]];

    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296,9999);

    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font
                                      constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                          lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];

    //adjust the label the the new height.
    CGRect newFrame = label.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
    newFrame.size.width = expectedLabelSize.width;
    NSLog(@"expectedlabelsizeheight %f", newFrame.size.height);
    label.frame = newFrame;
    [label setNeedsDisplay];
    [detailedBurger.commentField addSubview:label];
    NSLog(@"%f, %f", label.center.x, label.center.y);

}

// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];

UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.backgroundView.frame];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 900);

[scrollView addSubview:detailedBurger.view];
detailedBurger.view.center = CGPointMake(160, detailedBurger.view.frame.size.height/2);
[self.backgroundView addSubview:scrollView];
```

This code works if I explicitly set the frame with hard values(e.g. `label.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,10,10)`), but the dynamic sizing does not seem to work.

Console output:

```
2013-07-09 10:12:42.223 RateYourBurger[31439:c07] expectedlabelsizeheight 15.000000
2013-07-09 10:12:42.224 RateYourBurger[31439:c07] 10.000000, 20.000000
2013-07-09 10:12:42.224 RateYourBurger[31439:c07] expectedlabelsizeheight 15.000000
2013-07-09 10:12:42.224 RateYourBurger[31439:c07] 10.000000, 20.000000
2013-07-09 10:12:42.225 RateYourBurger[31439:c07] expectedlabelsizeheight 15.000000
2013-07-09 10:12:42.225 RateYourBurger[31439:c07] 10.000000, 20.000000
2013-07-09 10:12:42.226 RateYourBurger[31439:c07] expectedlabelsizeheight 15.000000
2013-07-09 10:12:42.226 RateYourBurger[31439:c07] 10.000000, 20.000000
2013-07-09 10:12:42.227 RateYourBurger[31439:c07] expectedlabelsizeheight 15.000000
2013-07-09 10:12:42.227 RateYourBurger[31439:c07] 10.000000, 20.000000
```

Comment: what this NSLog(@"expectedlabelsizeheight %f", newFrame.size.height); is printing?

Comment: edited with console output

Comment: Can you try to print newFrame before label.frame = newFrame; and paste the output.

Comment: why is your label.center.x == 0 ???? check this man. Check the width from the newFrame ?? Your width for the frame seems to be coming 0. Because you adjusted the height, but who will adjust the width from the new found expectedlabelsizeheight ??

Comment: the label.frame.size is 0,0 from the start.

Comment: @croyneaus4u I added newFrame.size.width = expectedLabelSize.width;
Not working yet. Also, see the new console output

Comment: What happens when you log the whole frame of the labels? What happens if you change to font to the system font? What happens when you set the background color to an actual color?

Comment: print `newFrame` and `detailedBurger.commentField.frame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic sizing does not work because you have to call method `setNeedsDisplay` after set the frame.

```
label.frame = newFrame;

[label setNeedsDisplay];
```

**Edit**

```
    NSString *text1 = @"This is my text This is my text This is my text This is my text This is my text This is my text This is my text This is my text";
    CGSize constraint1 = CGSizeMake(280, 2000);



 CGSize size1 = [text1 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12] constrainedToSize:constraint1 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];


    label.frame=CGRectMake(posx,posy,size1.width,size1.height);
    label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    label.numberOfLines = size1.height/15;
    [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
    label.text = text1;
    [label setNeedsDisplay];
```